# Do something with jquery after clicking a link to close a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, ratchet-bootstrap

I have a modal with the following code to close it

```
a#modalclick.icon.icon-close.pull-left href="#mymodal"
```

I want to know when the x icon is clicked and the modal closed so I can do something with the link id.

My javascript is;

```
$('#modalclick').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('clicked')
});
```

but it's not recognising the modal being clicked closed...

Comment: Can you try adding some more information to this, like the library used , a rough structure of modal etc. This much info does not give a clear picture.

Comment: using ratchet www.goratchet.com

Answer (score 0):

use these events `hidden.bs.modal`, `hide.bs.modal` [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

JS

```
$('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
console.log('modal is being to be closed')
});
$('#mymodal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(event) {
console.log('modal hidden')
});
```

Comment: I'm using ratchet which is like a mobile version of bootstrap... so that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: can you give me a fiddle ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using .not(':visible') ?

```
if ( $('#yourdiv').not(':visible') ) {
  console.log('not visible');
}
```